# Google play console screen crawlers not filling textinput fields

Tags: android, flutter, google-play-console, firebase-test-lab

I have recently build an app in flutter and i have submitted my app for closed testing.After few hours when pre-launch report was generated and i was able to make out that the crawlers is not filling my form which is needed to continue to the app(user have to enter username and phone number,Both of these are having constrains like user name cannot be more that 15 characters).
When i again sumbitted the same build for firebase test-lab and i was able to see the video, in that the video stops right where there is form.
And from screenshots from play console also shows the same.Only screen shot of my login page and fill form page.

NOTE:In google play console i have given `App Access` as `All functionality available without special access`

I'am code of my form page:

```
return Scaffold(
  body: SafeArea(
    child: Center(
      child: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Padding(
          padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 15.0.w),
          child: Column(
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
            children: [
              Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                child: Text(
                  "General Details",
                  style: TextStyle(
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.normal,
                      fontSize: 25,
                      color: prim),
                ),
              ),
              Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                child: textField(
                    textEditingController: namecontroller,
                    hint: "User name",
                    textInputType: TextInputType.name),
              ),
              Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                child: textField(
                    textEditingController: agecontroller,
                    hint: "Phone Number",
                    textInputType:
                        TextInputType.numberWithOptions(decimal: false)),
              ),
              Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                child: ElevatedButton(
                  style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                      primary: prim, padding: EdgeInsets.all(12)),
                  onPressed: () => savedetails(),
                  child: Text("Continue"),
                ),
              ),
              SizedBox(
                height: 12.h,
              )
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    ),
  ),
);
```

Is there any way to make the crawlers gor past the form screen,or is there any other issue which i'am missing out?
Any help is appreciated.